# How to create a systemd unit file for a play application

Tags: playframework, systemd

I'm happy with the process of writing a unit file, but it is the contents of the ExecStart (and related others) that I do not know how to lay out.

I've been given a command line for a play application that just states:

```
cd /play_home_dir
activator run
```

Can someone please help me with placing these commands inside a unit file?  Or explaining how best I can perform the above task with a unit file?

Comment: Don't you want to package the application as described here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Deploying#Build-a-server-distribution

Using those, you should be able to create a package containing the needed systemd files.

Comment: Thank you Frederic.  
But my problem is that I know nothing about Play or the application itself.
I was hoping that I could just make light of the startup script: "activator run" to get the application running.  It is just a test environment currently.
But if it is going to be more complicated - as your link suggests - then I shall go back to the developer and ask him for assistance in that direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a distribution first : sbt universal:package-zip-tarball for example. That create a binary distribution of the application.

On the systemd side :

```
[Unit]
Description=service1
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -f /usr/local/play/service1/RUNNING_PID
ExecStart=/usr/local/play/service1/bin/service1 -J-Xmx5120m -J-Xms3072m -J-server -Dlogger.file=/usr/local/play/service1/conf/application-live.xml -Dconfig.file=/usr/local/play/service1/conf/application-live.conf
User=play
Group=play
TimeoutStopSec=10
LimitNOFILE=10240

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

That assumes that :

The application is named service1, has the logger configuration in application-live.xml, and the application configuration in application-live.conf.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following commented system unit file in production.
Replace {{ app_name }} whith the name of you play project.
{{ app_version.stdout }} is the project version as specified in build.sbt
I am calling `play dist` and uploading the zip in `/opt`.

```
[Unit]
Description=The {{ app_name }} 
After=network.target
After=postgresql.service

[Service]
# Source environment for application
EnvironmentFile=/home/{{ app_name }}/app.env
EnvironmentFile=/home/{{ app_name }}/{{ env }}.env

# Up Evolutions should be safe on Production
# Down Evolutions are to be avoided
ExecStart=/opt/{{ app_name }}-{{ app_version.stdout }}/bin/{{ app_name }} \
    -Dhttp.address=localhost \
    -DapplyEvolutions.default=true \
    -Dpidfile.path=/var/run/{{ app_name }}/{{ app_name }}.pid
User={{ app_name }}
Group={{ app_name }}
WorkingDirectory=/opt/{{ app_name }}-{{ app_version.stdout }}

# Ensure /var/run/ {{ app_name }} is created before creating the pidfile
RuntimeDirectory={{ app_name }}

# See http://serverfault.com/a/695863
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I notived that after a hardpoweroff, the play startup was failing because postgresql was not available yet, hence the `After=postgresql.service`

I choosed to put my application configuration in environment variables, 
following the advice of https://12factor.net/config, so I am sourcing those with the `EnvironmentFile` directive.